# Is there any way to extract a rar file on cpanel

Tags: zip, cpanel, rar

I have a website script, it 212MB and it's in RAR format , I could not upload it via filezilla ftp , it gave me a timeout error after sometime, I could not upload it from the filemanager of cpanel as it also kept showing an error. Then I used a php script to upload it directly from the link but now I can not extract it as its RAR not ZIP. I converted the RAR into ZIP and have it on drop box and google drive but there is no direct link which I can use to upload via the php script, SO, Is there any way to extract the rar file from cpanel or using a php script or some other tweak. I have been working on it for 2 hours now and can not find a way around.

Comment: Can't you just upload the file to mega.nz or something like this, create an public link and upload the file via that link?

Comment: as I said, its over 200MB so wherever I upload it, i get a timeout. My upload speed is not good I guess.

Comment: A 212 MB script? Or an archive with all your web site files? Because the latter can probably just get expanded in your computer and uploaded individually.

Comment: Website files and Yes I tried that but there are 12,765 files inside , It uploaded for about 10 minutes on filezilla , then showed me timeout error. Only around 2000 files were uploaded. So I need to upload the zip somehow and extract it.

Comment: Then try to disable the filezilla timeout: _Settings_ -> Set _Timeout_ to 0

Comment: Its not fillezilla, Its the hosting server, Some files are too big so it gives a timeout when a file keeps uploading for a certain period of time

Comment: Okay, then unpack your archive on your PC and upload the files in smaller parts.

Comment: there are 12000 files, Can't be done like this. The bigger files won't upload anyway. Each file size is not the same.

Comment: May you try to contact your hosting providers support to find a way around, like you share the files on a cloud service and they download and upload it on the server.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

create a php file and extra the .rar with that php file. use the following code

```
$archive = RarArchive::open('archive.rar');
$entries = $archive->getEntries();
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    $entry->extract('/extract/to/this/path');
}
$archive->close();
```

Comment: did you put a proper path from the home directory?